# Python Lists - Finding Number of Times a String Occurs

Tags: python

How would I find how many times each string appears in my list?

Say I have the word:

```
"General Store"
```

that is in my list like 20 times. How would I find out that it appears 20 times in my list? I need to know this so I can display that number as a type of `"poll vote"` answer.

E.g:

```
General Store - voted 20 times
Mall - voted 50 times
Ice Cream Van - voted 2 times
```

How would I display it in a fashion similar to this?:

```
General Store
20
Mall
50
Ice Cream Van
2
```

Comment: Do you want it to be case-sensitive?

Comment: I doubt that matters, as I can just print the letters first, and then use a for loop, count the number of occurrences, and put those in there. But yes, I want them to be case sensitive. :)

Answer (score 17):

Use the `count` method. For example:

```
(x, mylist.count(x)) for x in set(mylist)
```

Answer (score 7):

While the other answers (using list.count) do work, they can be prohibitively slow on large lists.

Consider using `collections.Counter`, as describe in http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html

Example:

```
>>> # Tally occurrences of words in a list
>>> cnt = Counter()
>>> for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
...     cnt[word] += 1
>>> cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

Comment: Why not just `cnt = Counter(['red','blue','red','green','blue','blue'])` ?  As it is, you might as well be using `cnt = defaultdict(int)` -- which I suppose provides an O(N) way to do this in python 2.5 ... (as opposed to 2.7+ when Counter was introduced.)

Comment: I only copied this example from the collections doc page linked, but yes the `Counter([iterable])` constructor is definitely cleaner and simpler!

Answer (score 2):

just a simple example:

```
   >>> lis=["General Store","General Store","General Store","Mall","Mall","Mall","Mall","Mall","Mall","Ice Cream Van","Ice Cream Van"]
   >>> for x in set(lis):
        print "{0}\n{1}".format(x,lis.count(x))


    Mall
    6
    Ice Cream Van
    2
    General Store
    3
```

Answer (score 1):

First use set() to get all unique elements of the list. Then loop over the set to count elements from the list

```
unique = set(votes)
for item in unique:
    print item
    print votes.count(item)
```

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for, and I understand looping, but I do not know about the set function. I tried looking on http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-set but I still do not understand what I am setting. Maybe if you could explain what the votes is supposed to represent? Like I mean, do I put "General Store" in votes? But obviously that is supposed to go in "item" and you probably differentiated it for a reason.

Comment: 'votes' is your "list" containing duplicate strings that you want to count. And set() doesn't SET anything, it converts the list to a set by removing duplicates.

Comment: Ohh okay. I have got it to work now, but when I tried testing it, something like this occurs when I use the code:

Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Grain Products 0 Fruits and Vegetables 0 Fruits and Vegetables 0 Fruits and Vegetables 0 Fruits and Vegetables 0 Fruits and Vegetables 0 Fruits and Vegetables 0 

How would I make it just a single Category, getting all of the counts totalled in one place, and also, the

Comment: count goes to 0 if the user hits a different radio button at that moment. The .data file contains all of the choices, but it does not keep their count from before.

Comment: It looks like there is a lot more going on in your code that is not described here. Do you have a list/array object with all the strings for each vote?

Comment: I managed a small fix with this code:

pollList = set(poll)
grain = "Grain Products"
fruit = "Fruits and Vegetables"
meat = "Meats and Alternatives"
dairy = "Dairy Products"

print "<p>Grain Products</p>"
for grain in pollList:
    print int(poll.count("Grain Products"))

print "<p>Fruits and Vegetables</p>"
for fruit in pollList:
    print poll.count("Fruits and Vegetables")

print "<p>Meats and Alternatives</p>"
for meat in pollList:
    print poll.count("Meats and Alternatives")

print "<p>Dairy Products"
for dairy in pollList:
    print poll.count("Dairy Products")

Now, just trying to

Comment: get all of the counts into an added number. If the 0 did not appear there... maybe I could have collected and added all the 1's but with the others being 0, I do not know what to do.

Here is a portion of my output now:

Comment: Grain Products
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Fruits and Vegetables
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Meats and Alternatives
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Dairy Products
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: These are my scripts in case you need to know more info as to what I am messing up and my explanations come short:

http://pastebin.com/mDxEWnCX
http://pastebin.com/tbgXtpZz

Answer (score 1):

I like one-line solutions to problems like this:

```
def tally_votes(l):
  return map(lambda x: (x, len(filter(lambda y: y==x, l))), set(l))
```

Comment: I would imagine `list.count(x)` is more efficient than `len(filter(...))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary, you might want to consider just using a dictionary from the beginning instead of a list but here is a simple setup.

```
#list
mylist = ['General Store','Mall','Ice Cream Van','General Store']

#takes values from list and create a dictionary with the list value as a key and
#the number of times it is repeated as their values
def votes(mylist):
d = dict()
for value in mylist:
    if value not in d:
        d[value] = 1
    else:
        d[value] +=1

return d

#prints the keys and their vaules
def print_votes(dic):
    for c in dic:
        print c +' - voted', dic[c], 'times'

#function call
print_votes(votes(mylist))
```

It outputs:

```
Mall - voted 1 times
Ice Cream Van - voted 1 times
General Store - voted 2 times
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use the pandas library, this one is really quick:

```
import pandas as pd 

my_list = lis=["General Store","General Store","General Store","Mall","Mall","Mall","Mall","Mall","Mall","Ice Cream Van"]
pd.Series(my_list).value_counts()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
votes=["General Store", "Mall", "General Store","Ice Cream Van","General Store","Ice Cream Van","Ice Cream Van","General Store","Ice Cream Van"]

for vote in set(votes):
    print(vote+" - voted "+str(votes.count(vote))+" times")
```

Try this. It will output

```
General Store - voted 4 times
Ice Cream Van - voted 4 times
Mall - voted 1 times
```