# How Do you Find The Amount of the same str in a list?

Tags: python

How do you find if str is in a list, more than one time, and the amount?

```py
list = [hi, hi, bye ,hello]
if "hi" in list:
    print("hi is in the list")
```

That won't work since it does not show the amount that "hi" was in the list.

I would like it to output:
"hi" is in the list 2 times.
I hope this is a good question.

Comment: You might find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11800755/10576762) helpful

Comment: @AbsoluteSpace Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> > > myList=["a","a","a","b","c","c"]
> > >       myList.count('a')
> > >       3

Answer (score 0):

words = ['hi', 'hi', 'bye', 'hello']

answer = len([x for x in words if x == 'hi'])

You build a new list only using 'hi' and surround it with len(), which will count the number of positions.