# Given a list of urls, print out the top 3 frequent filenames

Tags: python, counting

Given a list of urls, print out the top 3 frequent filenames.

```
url = [
        "http://www.google.com/a.txt",
        "http://www.google.com.tw/a.txt",
        "http://www.google.com/download/c.jpg",
        "http://www.google.co.jp/a.txt",
        "http://www.google.com/b.txt",
        "http://facebook.com/movie/b.txt",
        "http://yahoo.com/123/000/c.jpg",
        "http://gliacloud.com/haha.png",
    ]
```

The program should print out

```
a.txt 3  
b.txt 2  
c.jpg 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Lists - Finding Number of Times a String Occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800755/python-lists-finding-number-of-times-a-string-occurs)

Comment: you should put what you have tried. we are here to help, not solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this with `collections.Counter`and **top 3** with `counter.most_common(3)`?

```
import collections
url = [
        "http://www.google.com/a.txt",
        "http://www.google.com.tw/a.txt",
        "http://www.google.com/download/c.jpg",
        "http://www.google.co.jp/a.txt",
        "http://www.google.com/b.txt",
        "http://facebook.com/movie/b.txt",
        "http://yahoo.com/123/000/c.jpg",
        "http://gliacloud.com/haha.png",
    ]

splited_url = [i.split('/')[-1] for i in url]
counter = collections.Counter(splited_url)
counter = counter.most_common(3)
for p in counter:
    print('{} {}'.format(p[0], p[1]))
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://rextester.com/EGJX25593

Answer (score 0):

How about using `re` and `collections` which provides a `Counter` and `most_common` to extract your top n hits!

```
import re
from collections import Counter

pattern = re.compile(r"\w+\.\w+$")
Counter(re.findall(pattern,u)[0] for u in url).most_common(3)
```

Output:

```
[('a.txt', 3), ('c.jpg', 2), ('b.txt', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` from collections:

```
from collections import Counter
res = [a.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] for a in url]
print (Counter(res))
#Counter({'a.txt': 3, 'c.jpg': 2, 'b.txt': 2, 'haha.png': 1})
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'a.txt': 3, 'c.jpg': 2, 'b.txt': 2, 'haha.png': 1})
```

***Link***:

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html

*UPDATE:*

OP asked about top 3:

```
    import collections
    kk = [a.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] for a in url]
    print (collections.Counter(kk).most_common(3))
    # [('a.txt', 3), ('c.jpg', 2), ('b.txt', 2)]
```

Comment: This will print all counts, but not the top n hits.

Comment: @Fourier Thanks! I updated